# Query to get total in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I need to find user_id with maximum fat_intake (overall fat_intake).

Database:

```
id | user_id | fat_intake 
38      1         10     
39      1         15         
40      1         30         
41      1         14         
42      2         20         
43      2         30         
44      2         50
```

What will be the query to get user_id with the maximum fat intake ?

The Response should be :

```
Output: 
  {
    "user_id": 1,
    "total_fat_count": 69
  }
```

I tried:

```
maxCalorie =  CalorieInfo.objects.annotate(fat_intake=Avg('fat_intake')).aggregate(Max('fat_intake'))
```

Comment: how 46 comes in picture ?

Comment: when you add all fat_intake by user 1 it's 46 @NishantNawarkhede

Comment: 10 + 15 + 30 + 14 = 69

Comment: i'm sorry it's actually 69, ill update @NishantNawarkhede

Comment: do you have an answer @NishantNawarkhede

Comment: @code_nation Have you tried anything? SO is not for asking a direct solution!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as,

```
In [27]: from django.db.models import Sum

In [28]: CalorieInfo.objects.all().values('user_id').annotate(fat_intake=Sum("fat_intake"))
Out[28]: <QuerySet [{'user_id': 1, 'fat_intake': 69}]>

In [29]:
```

Comment: Actually i have tried something and it didn't worked and the above is not working @Nishant Nawarkhede

Comment: just updated please check, your code is not giving total count

Answer (score 0):

this is the right answer it should work for you.

```
users.objects.values('user_id').annotate(total=Sum('fat_intake'))
```

the output is

```
<QuerySet [{'user_id': 1, 'total': 69}, {'user_id': 2, 'total': 100}]>
```